# How do I store related firebase data?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm making a firebase app where there's the concept of posts and authors.

I need to have a field called `postedBy` to give information about the post author. I'm currently confused on how to best implement this. Here's what I've thought about...

1. Store a `postedBy` field with the post author's `ID` as value. My issue with this is that I have to further send single requests for the user information, like name, profile picture etc.
2. I store a `postedBy` field with the exact clone of the author's data (name, profile URL, etc). My issue with this is what if the user changes their profile information? Do I have to loop through all the `posts` data to also ensure the changes?

What is the best way to solve an issue like this?

Comment: Please tag with *either* `firebase-realtime-database` **or** `google-cloud-firestore`, not with both. While both are part of Firebase, they are different and answers for one don't necessarily apply to the other.

Answer (score 0):

For your case, I would say that the best option would be probably to use only the `ID` as a value. This way, you can perform queries to return values using only the ID.

Using this approach should be the simplest and easiest way for you to create your application. Since the ID will be the point to connect your tables and to perform the queries, it should make your work easier.

In the below article, there is an example of a Blog application, that you can take a look and get some insights on how to configure your application as well - mainly about this part about author and post. :)

- [Learning Firebase: Creating a blog article object](https://medium.com/@tjmonsi/learning-firebase-creating-a-blog-article-object-making-a-blog-pt-2-c730e63fc82b)

Let me know if the information helped you!